# jQuery change href of parent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the `href` of the parent link to a header logo, but I am not successful. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<a href="https://URL.IWANTO.CHANGE">
    <img id="partner_logo" src="/partner_logos/P2.png" class="normal_logo">
</a>
```

I have the `id` of the `img`, I want to change the `src` of the parent `a`. I have tried these with no error nor success:

```
jQuery("#partner_logo").parent('a').attr('href', 'http://partner.web.site');
jQuery("#partner_logo").closest('a').attr('href', 'http://partner.web.site');
```

Comment: And what result does `console.log(jQuery("#partner_logo").length)` give?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I do in the code change the logo img src via  `jQuery("#partner_logo").attr('src', '/wp-content/uploads/partner_logos/' + logo);` so this part works. I want to change the `href` of the `a` that the `img` is wrapped with.

Comment: Your posted code should work, but does not. Which means the initial selector is not working, or you're wrong about your HTML. That's why I asked you the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code is correct (using the ...parent('a')...).

I suspect that you are calling the code at the wrong time.  Is the logo HTML inserted by another piece of code on page load or is it rendered with the initial html?

In any case, your call to .attr() should probably be in a $('document').ready() call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#partner_logo").parent('a').attr('href', 'http://partner.web.site');
    alert('set logo on load');
});


$('#partner_logo').on('click', function () {
     jQuery("#partner_logo").parent('a').attr('href', 'http://partner.web.site');
    alert('set logo on click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  You may want to change `parent('a')` to `parent()`

http://jsfiddle.net/upnrv7t2/

Comment: Yes, and so they should (the code from the question is fine, which suggests that the selector is the problem, not the method calls). Incidentally, this is more of a comment than any kind of answer. You may, or may not, wish to delete it (it's your call).